# Python web crawler using BeautifulSoup, trouble getting URLs

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

so I am trying to build a dynamic web crawler to get all url links within links.
so far i am able to get all the links for Chapters, but when I trying to do section links from each chapter, my output does not print out anything.

the code i used :

```
#########################Chapters#######################

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re


base_url = "http://law.justia.com/codes/alabama/2015/title-{title:01d}/"

for title in range (1,4): 
url = base_url.format(title=title)
r = requests.get(url)

 for link in BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
  if link.has_attr('href'):
    if 'chapt' in link['href']:
        href = "http://law.justia.com" + link['href']
        leveltwo(href)

#########################Sections#######################

def leveltwo(item_url):
 r = requests.get(item_url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser")
 section = soup.find('div', {'class': 'primary-content' })
 for sublinks in section.find_all('a'):
        sectionlinks = sublinks.get('href')
        print (sectionlinks)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some minor modifications to your code, I was able to get it to run and output the sections.  Mainly, you needed to fix your indentation, and define a function **before** you  call it.

```
#########################Chapters#######################

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re

def leveltwo(item_url):
    r = requests.get(item_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser")
    section = soup.find('div', {'class': 'primary-content' })
    for sublinks in section.find_all('a'):
        sectionlinks = sublinks.get('href')
        print (sectionlinks)

base_url = "http://law.justia.com/codes/alabama/2015/title-{title:01d}/"

for title in range (1,4): 
    url = base_url.format(title=title)
    r = requests.get(url)

for link in BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    try:
        if 'chapt' in link['href']:
            href = "http://law.justia.com" + link['href']
            leveltwo(href)
        else:
            continue
    except KeyError:
        continue
#########################Sections#######################
```

output:

`/codes/alabama/2015/title-3/chapter-1/section-3-1-1/index.html
/codes/alabama/2015/title-3/chapter-1/section-3-1-2/index.html
/codes/alabama/2015/title-3/chapter-1/section-3-1-3/index.html
/codes/alabama/2015/title-3/chapter-1/section-3-1-4/index.html etc.`

Comment: Thanks! I see what you did. Would it work, if I define a function of my part one for Chapters, and then a function for Sections "leveltwo" to refer back to part one?

Comment: yeah, if I'm understanding your correctly.  It'd also be much nicer to read if both 'sections' were wrapped in functions ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any try/except blocks, you can use `href=True` with find or `find_all` to only select the anchor tags with href's  or a css select `a[href]` as below, the chapter links are in the first *ul* with inside  the *article* tag with the id `#maincontent` so you don't need to filter at all:

```
base_url = "http://law.justia.com/codes/alabama/2015/title-{title:01d}/"
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def leveltwo(item_url):
    r = requests.get(item_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    section_links = [a["href"] for a in soup.select('div .primary-content a[href]')]
    print (section_links)



for title in range(1, 4):
    url = base_url.format(title=title)
    r = requests.get(url)
    for link in BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser").select("#maincontent ul:nth-of-type(1) a[href]"):
        href = "http://law.justia.com" + link['href']
        leveltwo(href)
```

If you were to use find_all you simply need to pass `find_all(.., href=True)` to  filter your anchor tags to only select ones that have hrefs.